# How did the wargs know the Fellowship's whereabouts?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Gandalf refers to the wargs that attack them at Hollin as hounds of Sauron, now if all the nazgul had left Eriador as it is hinted, how would the wargs know the whereabouts of the fellowship?

Maybe Sauron used his palantir to locate them, then order the wargs

Comment: How to hounds normally find their pray?

Comment: Hundreds of little birdies told them? My guess is spies ratted out Gandalf & Co.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't clear, as far as the text itself is concerned.  According to Robert Foster's *The Complete Guide to Middle-earth*, which Christopher Tolkien himself has used as a reference, and to which he paid a good deal of praise, the "wargs" at Hollin weren't real.

> The wargs [at Hollin] do not seem to have been true Wargs, in that they were west of the Misty Mountains and weren't real.

By "real", he seems to be referring to the fact that the corpses of the dead wargs had vanished overnight.  As far as we know, true wargs don't vanish upon being killed - for instance, Beorn kills a warg in *The Hobbit*, then skins it and nails its hide to a tree near his house.  This would be impossible if wargs disappeared when they died.

I haven't been able to find any information about how the wargs - whether or not they real - found the Fellowship.  However, one interpretation of the Fellowship's ordeal on Caradhras - that Sauron was responsible for the storm - might explain this pretty well.

If Sauron was indeed responsible for the storm that nearly killed the Hobbits, then it stands to reason that he would have seen the Fellowship's retreat, including the direction in which they headed after descending the mountain.  If this is the case, it would have been relatively easy for Sauron to harass their campsite with phantom wargs.

And the following quote, kindly supplied by Matt Gutting, would appear to support this theory:

> "That day the weather changed again, **almost as if it was at the command of some power that... wished now to have a clear light in which things that moved in the wild could be seen far away**."
>   -  *The Fellowship of the Ring, Book II, Chapter 4, "A Journey In The Dark"*

Comment: Interestingly, Tolkien uses "was", not "were" there - indicative, not subjunctive.